# How to change the default delimiter of mustache.js?

Tags: javascript, mustache, delimiter

Could someone please tell me how to change the default delimiter for mustache.js? The default delimiter is `{{var}}` and I would like to change it to `{|var|}`

I have the following code:

```
$('body').append(Mustache.render(this.template, data));
```

Many thanks

Comment: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#set-delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app.js, use the last line in the following snippet. The first 2 are for reference:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/templates'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');
app.locals.delimiters = '{| |}';
```

Answer (score 8):

As [per the documentation](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#set-delimiter):

*Set Delimiter tags start with an equals sign and change the tag delimiters from {{ and }} to custom strings.
Consider the following contrived example:*

```
* {{ default_tags }}
{{=<% %>=}}
* <% erb_style_tags %>
<%={{ }}=%>
* {{ default_tags_again }}
```

So for your case where you want to use `{|var|}` you could probably use:

```
{{={| |}=}}
```

Note, here is [another example that changes the default delimiter to triple-mustaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944623/escape-double-braces-in-mustache-template-templating-a-template-in-n).

Comment: thanks Casey, so do I need to add anything to the line of code: $('body').append(Mustache.render(this.template, data)); or do I just update the mustache tags in my template? Im confused around how the mustache lib knows I'm using custom delimiters?

Comment: The documentation and example seem to imply that that is all you need. Notice the equals signs in the code above; you literally are setting each template tag start/end to a new value. It probably checks the direction  of the assignment and the current assigned values to check which part of the template tag to change. Make sense?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this no longer the standard method?

Comment: Just add the delimiter change before your template, something along the lines of `$('body').append(Mustache.render('{{={| |}=}} ' + this.template, data));` worked for me.

Comment: I need exactly this feature because I use mustache for TeX and there I also need "unescaped" fields, and the "&" operator comes in handy here: instead of `{{{field}}}` it is possible to write - with custom delimiters `<%` and `%>` the unescaped field as `<% & field %>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a javascript example will be helpful too.

```
var template = $('#template').html();
var parseTags = new Array();
parseTags.push("[[");
parseTags.push("]]");
Mustache.parse(template,parseTags);   // optional, speeds up future uses
var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {name: "<%Luke%>"});
```

Comment: Please don't dump code, perhaps [edit] your answer and add some details how this bit of code can help

Answer (score 0):

There's a much neater way to do this now and it's documented well.
https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

```
var customTags = [ '<%', '%>' ];

Mustache.render(template, view, {}, customTags);
//Either tell mustache to use them each time
Mustache.render(template, view, {}, customTags);
//Or override the tags property and Mustache knows what to do until you tell it otherwise
Mustache.tags = customTags;
var updateTemplate = '<small class="text-muted">Last updated <% updated_at %> by <% updated_by %></small>';
var html = Mustache.render(updateTemplate, {updated_at:'2019-11-18 14:54:20',updated_by:'abc'});
```