# What is the difference between Laravel setEscapedContentTags and setContentTags?

Tags: php, templates, laravel-5

To better understand how Laravel tag settings work, I tried the following:

```
Blade::setContentTags('<x', 'x>');
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<y', 'y>');
Blade::setRawTags('<z', 'z>');
```

in my controller constructor.

In Blade view, I added

```
<div>
  <x 'test' x>
  <y 'test' y>
  <z 'test' z>
</div>
```

I cleaned storage/framework/views folder and reloaded the page.

As a result, in compiled view I got

```
<div>
    <?php echo e('test'); ?>

    <?php echo e('test'); ?>

    <?php echo 'test'; ?>

</div>
```

**As you see, the code compiled for tags specified with setContentTags and setEscapedContentTags looks the same. Why do we need both of these options then?**

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of safety reason.
By default, `Blade` will return equal results for content with regular and escaped tags. `BladeCompiler` class has protected property `$echoFormat` with value `e(%s)`. This property is used when content compiles with *regular tags* (in your case it's 'x').

```
/**
 * The "regular" / legacy echo string format.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $echoFormat = 'e(%s)';
```

The property works as a placeholder for the function `e`

```
/**
 * Escape HTML entities in a string.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
function e($value)
{
    return htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
}
```

The `e` function is also called when content compiles with *escaped tags* (in your case it's 'y')

Your can change format also:

```
/**
 * Set the echo format to be used by the compiler.
 *
 * @param  string  $format
 * @return void
 */
public function setEchoFormat($format)
{
    $this->echoFormat = $format;
}
```

With default settings `Blade` will return different results for content with `regular` and `escaped tags` if you prefix your text with an `@` symbol.

**For view param**

```
['str' => "<script>alert('name')</script>"]
```

**With template**

```
<div>@{{ $str }}</div>
<div>@{{{ $str }}}</div>

<div>@{{"<a>Plain text</a>"}}</div>
<div>@{{{"<a>Plain text</a>"}}}</div>
```

**The result will be**

```
<div>{{ $str }}</div>
<div>@&lt;script&gt;alert(&#039;name&#039;)&lt;/script&gt;</div>

<div>{{"<a>Plain text</a>"}}</div>
<div>@&lt;a&gt;Plain text&lt;/a&gt;</div>
```