# Place a brace just before {{# ... }} in Mustache templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, mustache, template-engine

I want to place a brace just before {{# .. }} expression Mustache expression. How can I do this?
For example, for these inputs:

#### Input 1

Hash:

```
{
  "things": []
}
```

Output:

```
<pre>
{}
</pre>
```

#### Input 2

Hash:

```
{
  "things": [
    { "name": "thing1" },
    { "name": "thing2" },
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
<pre>
{
  listOfThings: [
    "thing1",
    "thing2",
  ]
}
</pre>
```

The example is a bit synthetic in order to preserve simplicity.

My initial idea didn't work:

```
<pre>
\{{{#things}}
  {{name}}
{{/things}}\}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [HTML Entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) for the desired literal curly braces in the output. Your example template would become the following:

```
<pre>
    &lbrace;{{#things}}
        {{name}}
    {{/things}}&rbrace;
</pre>
```

However, I would like to point out that this template does *not* produce the desired output stated in your question. For that, you would need something like the following:

```
<pre>
&lbrace;
    listOfThings: [
        {{#each things}}
           "{{name}}",
        {{/each}}
    ]
&rbrace;
</pre>
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpoaavd7/) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Discovering something new in web every day :D

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper to output curly brackets.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('curly', function(object, open) {
    return open ? '{' : '}';
});
```

You can use it as follows.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{curly true}}{{name}}{{curly}}
</script>
```

If you are passing true to `curly`, it will show the opening bracket. Else it'll show the closing bracket.

Output would be as follows.

```
{Stack Over Flow Rocks}
```

Answer credits to [Escape double braces {{ ... }} in Mustache template. (templating a template in NodeJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944623/escape-double-braces-in-mustache-template-templating-a-template-in-n)

Comment: Thanks. That solves the issue but I hoped for a bit simpler solution.